# dist-upgrade cant be finished - problems with lxd - Ubuntu 18.04 - fail certbot install

Tags: upgrade, error-handling, lxd

Good evenening,

i use Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and i want use this command to Upgrade the Server (before i did update):

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

it shows me that there are some errors:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
lxd (3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) wird eingerichtet ...

Old bridge configuration detected in /etc/default/lxd-bridge, upgrading
Unsetting deprecated profile options
Error: unknown command "profile" for "lxc"

Did you mean this?
        Profil

Run 'lxc --help' for usage.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes lxd (--configure):
 »installiertes lxd-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Trigger für libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 lxd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i also used

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and i get back this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
lxd (3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) wird eingerichtet ...

Old bridge configuration detected in /etc/default/lxd-bridge, upgrading
Unsetting deprecated profile options
Error: unknown command "profile" for "lxc"

Did you mean this?
        Profil

Run 'lxc --help' for usage.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes lxd (--configure):
 »installiertes lxd-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Trigger für libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.6) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 lxd
```

the mail Part is that i want to install Certbot but i cant do this - i tryed to update the Server but yeah.

hopefully you can help me. If you need more necessary things please tell me. The Errors are in German but i hope you can interpret it correct.

regards Max

Comment: If you are trying to move fron one version of Ubuntu to another that is the wrong command. The correct command is sudo do-release-upgrade Else before upgrade you need to do sudo apt-get update.

Comment: Hello, thanks for that Information, but i just want to have up2date the 18.04 for now. and i also Update bevore Upgrade. Regards